# Access data-* attribute in HTML and pass it as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

How do I access the data-* attribute which is specified in HTML to be passed as props ?

If it is a normal attribute then we use `this.getAttribute('class')`, in case of using `data-class` webpack adds space `data - class`. How can we avoid webpack from adding space between hyphen.

**UPDATE**: May be I need to be more specific, WebPack adds space while generating the code which contains the React Component props.

The generated code looks like,

```
_createClass(App, [{
            key: 'render',
            value: function render() {
                debugger;
                return _react2.default.createElement(
                    'div',
                    null,
                    _react2.default.createElement(_header2.default, { options: this.props.options }),
                    _react2.default.createElement(_footer2.default, { options: this.props.data - footeroptions })
                );
            }
        }]);
```

Comment: *"webpack adds space `data - class`"* That seems...unlikely.

Comment: WebPack might add spaces for `this.getAttribute(data-class)` but it definitely won't for `this.getAttribute('data-class')`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the generated code.

Comment: Can you show the code that the example was generated from?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use string literals when referring to object properties with hyphens.

```
this.props.data-footeroptions
// should be written as
this.props.data['footeroptions']
```

Also for reference, I think this is probably a JSX problem, rather than WebPack.